# css flip counter - cannot set proper pace

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter

I have implement the css/js flip counter from Chris Nanney of which you can see the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/H4PLA/1/.

Problem that I have is that I would expect by setting the ad hoc parameters in the code below, I could define a:
- start value,
- end value,
- increment value,
- pace,
with this script at the end of my html page:

```
var value = 0;
var endVal = 99;
var inc = 9;  //between 0 and 1000
var pace = 400; // between 400 and 2000
var nextCount;

var myCounter = new flipCounter('flip-counter', {
 value: value,
 auto: false
 });

  function doCount() {
 value = value + inc >= endVal ? value + inc : endVal;
 myCounter.setValue(value);
 nextCount = value != endVal ? setTimeout(doCount, pace) : null;
  }

  doCount();
```

Somehow though, the end result (value=99) is shown straight away with no live dynamic increment between 0 and 99. 
Has someone got any idea why ? Thanks.

Comment: I ran your fiddle and nothing happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `value = value + inc >= endVal ? value + inc : endVal;` sets the value to endVal if value + inc is LOWER than endVal, do you really want that? I believe what you want is `value = value + inc <= endVal ? value + inc : endVal;`

Comment: You're welcome. Just keep going, everything is about exercising :)

Answer (score 1):

```
value = value + inc >= endVal ? value + inc:endVal;
```

This line skips right to the end, because the right side of the `:` will trigger when `value + inc >= endVal` is false, which it is. `value + inc` is not greater than the `endVal` in the beginning.

```
nextCount = value != endVal ? setTimeout(doCount, pace) : null;
```

This line is just confusing, you don't even use the next count variable, and the timeout does not return a useful value. How about this for clarity:

```
if ( value != endVal ) setTimeout(doCount, pace)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bad comparision, change `>=` to `<` in `doCount function`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 1328;
var endVal = 2750;
var inc = 1; //Change
var pace = 600;
var nextCount;

var myCounter = new flipCounter('flip-counter', {
    value: value,
    auto: false
});

function doCount() {
    value = value + inc < endVal ? value + inc : endVal; // Change
    myCounter.setValue(value);
    nextCount = value != endVal ? setTimeout(doCount, pace) : null;
}

doCount();
```

Comment: please elaborate on your answer, it's hard to tell what you actually changed from the original code the OP pasted...